# Objective C:Object Deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, key-value-observing

I am hitting the below error after I added 2 additional fields to my core data model.

```
CarPark_CarPark_ was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Observation info was leaked, and may even become mistakenly attached to some other object. 
Set a breakpoint on NSKVODeallocateBreak to stop here in the debugger. 
Here's the current observation info:
<NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x1b6510> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x19b210: Observer: 0x1a8cf0, Key path: coordinate, 
Options: <New: NO, Old:     NO, Prior: YES> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x1b7e00>
)
```

I am a little lost on what to do next. Any guidance on this will be greatly greatly appreciated! Please let me know what other information is required.

Comment: Have you followed the recommendation to set a breakpoint on NSKVODeallocateBreak? That could help you to figure out where the problem comes from.

Comment: @omz, pardon my ignorance, how can I set this breakpoint on NSKVODeallocateBreak?

Comment: I didn't set any oberservers in my application. But what does this actually mean? "Here's the current observation info:
<NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x1ac3a0> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x1ac360: Observer: 0x19af20, Key path: coordinate, Options: <New: NO, Old: NO, Prior: YES> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x1ac3e0>"

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To set the breakpoint open the breakpoints tab in Xcode 4 (Breakpoints window in Xcode 3) and add a new symbolic Breakpoint for the symbol "NSKVODeallocateBreak"

Use the debugger console to print the observer at the adress given in the observation info

Observer: 0x19af20

```
po 0x19af20
```

This should give some valuable information about the observer.
Override addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context: in your custom CarPark class and set a breakpoint to see the exact location of the observing being established.

Comment: fantastic! Great way to find leaking

Answer (score 9):

It's probably due to the observer being deallocated before the objects being observed. You would need to implement the **-(void) dealloc** method to remove all observed objects in the observer.