# How to build Facebook iOS sdk for armv7s?

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

Is it possible to build facebook ios sdk to support for armv7s(Apple A6 cpu)?
I have try to use build_framework.sh to rebuild again, it still not support armv7s yet!

Comment: Take a look at [this Stack Overflow post][1] it's a simple tutorial to build Facebook iOS SDK.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12540137

Answer (score 4):

I compiled the source code and shared it at http://db.tt/QpIjMfWb. It will be removed after fb updates the SDK.

Comment: I used what you sent, it looks like its not compiled also for armv6.. is this correct?

Comment: @elads Yes. Xcode 4.5 dropped  support to armv6. I suggest you use the official Facebook 3.1 sdk.

Answer (score 2):

I just followed this link today:
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/107674376052717
it says that they will roll out a new update that will solve the problem.
Try downloading the latest source and re-compiling.

Answer (score 1):

Check the latest 3.1 SDK, that should resolve this issue.