# What we do with Third library that don't have armv7s slice

Tags: iphone, architecture, ios6, armv7

in my project i have a Third Library that don't have the armv7s slice for the new iPhone, so i want to know how i can set the Project Target Architecture, and the Third Library Architecture to work with iPhone 5...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply remove `armv7s` from Valid Architectures in your build settings.

See [File is universal (three slices), but it does not contain a(n) ARMv7-s slice error for static libraries on iOS, anyway to bypass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402092/file-is-universal-3-slices-but-does-not-contain-an-armv7s-slice-error-for-st) and [Facebook SDK for iOS6/Xcode 4.5 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12513222/facebook-sdk-for-ios6-xcode-4-5-not-working).

Comment: thanks for the answer, and if i simply remove the armv7s work on iphone 5?

Comment: It will run, yes, but as pointed out in the questions that I linked to it's not a permanent solution. It'd be best to try and get the library compiled specifically with armv7s support, or compile it yourself.

Comment: i have no idea how to compile it for armv7s :(...however i don't understand if i have to remove the armv7s only for the static library, or also for the main project target...

Comment: Select your project, select your app under 'Targets', then in 'Build Settings' just remove armv7s from 'Valid Architectures'. If you don't know how to recompile it, it's probably best to wait for it to be done by the developers. :)

Comment: ok so i have to do it ONLY for the main project right?, i don't think so the developer do it, because it a old project, it's the Parse Kit...you have idea if there is a tutorial or something to learn how to compile it?

Comment: Yes, for the main target. If the source code of the library is available, you'll be able to recompile it.

Comment: Ok thanks, but have any idea how to recompile it? this is the library https://github.com/itod/parsekit, is open source...

Comment: @ev0lution So if it will run on iPhone5, what is the downside ??

Comment: @EralpB There are CPU-specific optimisations that your app will miss out on if it's run on a newer device, because it's restricted to an older CPU instruction set. There won't be a noticeable difference unless your app does lots (seriously lots) of mathematical operations that would use these optimisations. This question was asked after the introduction of the iPhone 5 and armv7s - now with the 5s and 6/6+, we also have the arm64 instruction set.